# assign vector-valued function output to a vector

Tags: matlab

I'd like to assign the results of a vector-valued function `f` as below, on the `%this does not` line.  Is there a way to do this?

file `scratch.m`:

```
function scratch(x)
get_f(x)
end

% vector-valued function of a vector
function val = f(x)
val(1) = x(1)^3 + x(2) - 1;
val(2) = x(2)^3 - x(1) + 1;
end

function get_f(x)
%  z = f(x)  % this works
[x1,x2] = f(x);  % this does not
end
```

call with `scratch([1,1])`:

```
>> scratch([1,1])
Error using scratch>f
Too many output arguments.

Error in scratch>get_f (line 12)
[x1,x2] = f(x);

Error in scratch (line 2)
get_f(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function output `val` is a 1x2 array, not 2 individual variables, so you must call it like this:

```
arrayX = f(x);
x1 = arrayX(1);
x2 = arrayX(2);
```

If you want 2 output variables instead you need to change your function body like this:

```
function [y1, y2] = f(x)
    y1 = x(1)^3 + x(2) - 1;
    y2 = x(2)^3 - x(1) + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Force a conversion to a cell array

```
function [x1, x2] = Untitled2(x)
    [x1, x2] = get_f(x);
end

% vector-valued function of a vector
function val = f(x)
    val(1) = x(1)^3 + x(2) - 1;
    val(2) = x(2)^3 - x(1) + 1;
end

function [x1, x2] = get_f(x)
    %  z = f(x)  % this works
    z = num2cell(f(x));
    [x1, x2] = z{:};
end
```